# How to use Reverse Proxy in OpenLiteSpeed?

Tags: node.js, deployment, reverse-proxy, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

I want to deploy my nodejs application that contains backend and frontend for my application in openlitespeed.

I run both of them using pm2 autorunner and get the port that i setup earlier (For example i using port 8080). How can i use reverse proxy like nginx in openlitespeed? is there are step by step to do that?

i expect it to run in url like this `localhost/downtime-app` without using port

Actually i already set my index.html of my frontend to configured like php but when i refresh the page it will return page error 503, and i already add .htaccess in directory of my builded nodejs fe but it not working, so i want to use reverse proxy if it possible.

information :
i use .htaccess like this

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>```
````

Comment: what do you mean by "localhost/downtime-app without using port" ? do you have a domain or not ? do you mean "domain.com/downtime-app" ?

Comment: yep i mean <IP>/downtime-app , so like redirecting to port 80 but with additional prefix in url. @OmarAtri

Comment: I am not sure that I understood what you want, but [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77712065/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-to-cyberpanel/77713025)

Comment: Thank you, for the link information, and it Works! only a few context setup needed. Thanks a lot @OmarAtri